# How to find the shortest path that visits all nodes of a non-complete graph (repeating nodes allowed)?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal

Let $G$ be a non-complete weighted (only positive weights) undirected connected graph. I'm trying to find a path such that it visits all nodes *at least* once (repeating nodes is allowed), and it's the shortest one. Length of the path is defined as the sum of weights of all traversed edges, including the repeated ones. This problem is similar to having to visit all locations, and do a U-turn when there's a dead-end. It's not the same as the traveling salesman problem.

My graph has at most 25 vertices, and each one has at most 4 edges.

I tried several greedy algorithms but none work for all cases. Also, researched the literature and Google but most algorithms found are slightly different, and I couldn't adapt them.

Comment: With 25 vertices, you can use brute-force solutions. However, naive brute-force can require $n!$ time, which is too much. By using a dynamic programming-like approach (where your state is the current vertex and the set of visited vertices), you can achieve $2^n$ time (maybe multiplied by $n$ or $n^2$), and you can solve it in a second.

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks. I also thought about using that approach and think it can actually be a great idea. I haven't implemented it yet but will try, thanks!

Comment: @dmitry I wouldn't call the Bellman–Held–Karp algorithm brute force.

Comment: @Dmitry make that into an answer?

Comment: @PålGD, maybe you are right. I call it brute-force since it's more or less an exhaustive search. Didn't know it has a name though!

Comment: @dmitry but it's not an exhaustive search, right? That's the point, it reduces the search space exponentially.

Comment: @PålGD, I get what you are saying, but I think it's a matter of perception: we still need to iterate over all possible states, and since the number of states is exponential (although, as you said, much smaller than the naive search space), I perceive it as brute-force.